# How to change the logName and configure the stackdriver logging agent in Container-Optimized OS?

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-container-os

I want to setup an export for logs generated in a [Container-Optimized OS](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/) using [Stackdriver Exports](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/).

In case of Linux VM instance, I know that the logName is taken from the file like `/etc/google-fluentd/config.d/[APPLICATION_NAME].conf`. For example: 
Below is the how `/etc/google-fluentd/config.d/syslog.conf` looks in a Linux VM:

```
<source>
  @type tail

  # Parse the timestamp, but still collect the entire line as 'message'
  format syslog

  path /var/log/syslog
  pos_file /var/lib/google-fluentd/pos/syslog.pos
  read_from_head true
  tag some-log-name
</source>
```

According to the above conf file the logName in StackDriver logs will be **"projects/[PROJECT-NAME]/logs/some-log-name"**. Here is the resource which explains the configuration of Logging Agent, in case where the agent is installed manually.

Now, in the case of CONTAINER-OPTIMIZED OS, there is no folder named `/etc/google-fluentd`, and I am not able to find out the conf file where I change the logName to reflect in the [StackDriver Log Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview). As of now here is an example of log generated by this VM:

```
{
   insertId:  "some-random-id"  
   jsonPayload: {…}  
   logName:  "projects/[PROJECT-NAME]/logs/gcplogs-docker-driver"  
   receiveTimestamp:  "2019-03-28T13:10:31.609437487Z"
   resource: {…}  
   timestamp:  "2019-03-28T13:10:30.588317266Z"
}
```

In the above log, I don't know where *gcplogs-docker-driver* is coming from in the logName. I am looking for a way to change that.

(P.S. Changing the log name is important for me because, the sinks created to export logs in a [google cloud bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets) creates a directory whose name is identical to the logName tag (for `logName:  "projects/[PROJECT-NAME]/logs/gcplogs-docker-driver`, a directory called 
 `gcplogs-docker-driver` will be created.)

Answer (score 3):

> Now, in the case of CONTAINER-OPTIMIZED OS, there is no folder named /etc/google-fluentd, and I am not able to find out the conf file where I change the logName to reflect in the StackDriver Log Viewer.

The `/etc/google-fluentd` folder is used to store the config file for the Stackdriver Logging agent ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/), [code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-fluentd)).

On Container-optimized OS, the agent is containerized and managed by [stackdriver-logging.service](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/overlays/board-overlays/+/refs/heads/master/overlay-lakitu/app-admin/stackdriver/files/stackdriver-logging.service), and the [config file](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/overlays/board-overlays/+/refs/heads/master/overlay-lakitu/app-admin/stackdriver/files/logging_configs/fluentd-lakitu.conf) is stored at `/etc/stackdriver/logging.config.d`.

You will need to run `sudo systemctl start stackdriver-logging` to start the agent.

> I don't know where gcplogs-docker-driver is coming from in the logName. I am looking for a way to change that.

These logs actually comes from a completely different source. They comes from a Docker logging driver: [Google Cloud Logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/gcplogs/). Looking at the documentation, apparently they do not provide any way to configure the log name.

And looking at their source code, apparently this log name is [hard-coded](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/9a2c26374393e0f46e8f2b1e49d2dcf66b78dbb4/daemon/logger/gcplogs/gcplogging.go#L161) in Docker's source code. So I'm afraid that there is no good way to configure the log name for the gcplogs Docker logging driver.